# How do you take wheel locks off a '95 Mercury Tracer?

Tags: wheels, locks, mercury

[image]I have a 1995 Mercury Tracer Trio that needs new tires. I do not have the wheel lock key/tool to remove them though. Is there an alternate way to remove them without having to take it to a mechanic?

Comment: Are you referring to locking lug nuts? Do you have a picture?

Comment: It depends on the type of nuts fitted - Some can be removed with readily-available tools, others will need to be taken to a professional... As @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing says, could you please post a picture?

Comment: Look on amazon for the key

Comment: Just posted a picture. I've even contacted a Ford dealership and the technician told me that he doesn't have keys for that old of a vehicle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a wheel lock removing set.

[image]

I believe most automotive stores will sell them. They can also easily be  found online.

Or you can drill the nut and stud. Which takes a long time. It would be faster & cheaper to pay a mechanic for a half hour labor to remove your wheel locks.

Comment: Now we're talkin.  One more down.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you'll have to take that to a shop - I had a very similar set of locks on a car before, I tried using a remover set like the one in Ben's answer, but it didn't get anywhere - the outer chromed ring split in two circumferentially and just span - the tyre shop used a special single-use tool that was hammered into the keyhole and deformed to fit.